# Uma forma de comparação em python

Tags: python, array, comparação

Olá, tenho o seguinte vetor em minhas mãos[image: vetor]

e gostaria de saber como posso compará-lo quando isso([]) está vazio... sou iniciante em python e tentei `if separa == '[]'` mas como eu suspeitava nao funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em `python` aspas (duplas ou simples) indicam que o conteúdo que está dentro delas é uma `string`, desse modo, ao fazer a comparação `if separa == '[]'`, você está comparando se a variável `separa` é igual a string `'[]'`.

Para saber se a lista está vazia, basta fazer o seguinte:

```python
if not separa:
```

Em `python`, uma lista em um condicional retorna `True` se possuir ao menos um elemento, e `False` se estiver vazia.
Outra forma (menos *`pythonica`*), seria:

```python
if separa == []:
```

Repare que não usamos aspas, pois estamos comparando a variável do tipo `lista` com uma lista vazia, e não com uma `string`.

Uma terceira forma de checar se uma lista está vazia, é usando a função `built-in` (isto é, nativa da linguagem), `len()`:

```python
if len(separa) == 0:
```

A função `len` retorna o tamanho da variável iterável (seja uma string, uma lista, um dicionário, etc), ou seja, a quantidade de elementos dentro dessa estrutura.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda